# How can I replace Email addresses with BitMessage Addresses througout wordpress?

Tags: wp-mail, subscription

BitMessage (bitmessage.org) is a peer-to-peer email system kind of based on BitTorrent. By itself, this software and its' messages are not compatible with email, so in order to send an email to a bitmessage address, a Gateway service has been created here: https://bitmessage.ch

The gateway works by simply allowing anyone to send an email to **{bitmessage-address}@bitmessage.ch**

This is a less secure way of using bitmessage of course, but I don't see any other way of setting wordpress up to natively use bitmessage.

So my question is: How exactly do I change out the email address field  of wordpress 3.9.1 to a Bitmessage address field, & what exactly do I need to change in which files to ensure that "@bitmessage.ch" is attached to the end of the bitmessage address at any & all email send requests?

Thanks in advance! 
SYG

Comment: What have you tried? What *exact* problem are you encountering? If you have relevant code, please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/147834/edit) to add it so we can try to help out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with wordpress internal code and just barely know enough PHP to try to attempt making the changes you guys point out. I'm really asking for help on locating the affected code. For instance, where inside the wp-mail.php file would changes need to be made? Seemed overwhelming when I opened it up. :(

Comment: So just to be clear, whenever WP tries to send mail to a user, you just need to swap `user@bitmessage.org` for `user@bitmessage.ch`?

Comment: No, a BM username has no @ sign in it... It looks like this:  BM-3908ru9084ur09qu098udf0   Therefore, I want users to enter just BM-3908ru9084ur09qu098udf0 while in the background a @bitmessage.ch is added to that making it BM-3908ru9084ur09qu098udf0@bitmessage.ch